# I just want to have knowledge about heroku plans?

Tags: heroku

Can a plan I buy on Heroku address the h12(request timeout) issue? Because when I attempt the free version, I always get an H12 error. I apologise in advance. I'm just curious if buying it will fix the mistake. Since I receive a h12 error when using the free plan.

Comment: No, you cannot buy your way out of H12 errors. You'll have to fix the root cause. There is [quite a lot of documentation about doing that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout).

Comment: Side note: [Heroku's free plans are going away entirely in about a week and a half](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter).

Comment: @Chris maybe my web app need a lot of web process so i don' get the h12 error? Because in free plan only web process is available?

Comment: There are any number of ways to get a request timeout. You're going to have to get a _lot_ more specific about your application if you expect to get help here. Linking to the documentation, as I did in my first comment, is the best answer we can provide for this question in its current form. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

H12 - Request Timeout is an error that is recorded when it takes more than 30 seconds to complete an HTTP request of an application. First, it is necessary to fix the application to respond within 30 seconds. Heroku provides the following related articles.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/addressing-h12-errors-request-timeouts
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preventing-h12-errors-request-timeouts